# How to over-ride CSS in content management system

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, sharepoint-2007

I'm building a page on my company's intranet, which runs on Sharepoint 2007. I'm trying to use tables to better organize the page, but it appears that there is a style sheet which defines all tables as having borders and grey backgrounds. I'd like to change the formatting of the table, but cannot find a way around the style sheet.

When I enter the HTML editor, I have tried updating the HTML within the table, but no luck. I tried adding CSS in this editor as well, but no dice. I'm an amateur at this kind of thing, so not sure how best to proceed. Is there any way to over-ride this CSS and get the style of table that I want?

Comment: Are the tables for actual data? Or are you trying to use them to layout the page? If it's the latter, then I suggest you not use tables and use block elements, like `divs`. If it's actual table data, and you can't use inline-css, then I would say you might be out of luck - unless you can add your own stylesheet to the Sharepoint server.

Answer (score 0):

How is the table accessed? If it is selected by just the table tag in css, then you can't really do anything unless you give all the tables a class.  If it is selected by a class, you can change the class for just that one table that you want to change. If you want to keep some of the attributes, make the table have a different id, create a selector in css for that id, and add the attributes that you want to keep. For example...

```
<table class = 'table'>
<tr>
<td>example<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>example2<td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class = 'table'>
<tr>
<td>example<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>example2<td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class = 'table'>
<tr>
<td>example<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>example2<td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class = 'table2'>
<tr>
<td>example<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>example2<td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class = 'table'>
<tr>
<td>example<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>example2<td>
</tr>
</table>


<style>
.table{
border:solid 5px black;
}
.table2{
border:solid 5px purple
}
</style>
```

in this example, I made all the other tables have a class, and just changed the class for the one table that I wanted to change.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by playing around with it a bit more. By adding inline CSS to the table, and individual cells, I was able to get what I needed. It's not ideal, but allows me to layout the page much better. Thank you for your help.